# Heatmap of events, I can't get the right resolution

Tags: qgis, heat-map

With QGIS 3.2.3., I'm trying to create a heatmap of a set of events (ie: bikes passing on a road). This is the original vector.

[image]

What I'm trying to get is a heatmap with darker colour where a lot of bikes have passed, and light colour where a few have.

I've tried two approaces:

1) Gdal > Vector Conversion > Rasterize

2) Interpolation > Heatmap (Kernel Density)

I've tried with several parameters, but I always get, a result which is not satisfactory:

1) I get a single pixel where I had an event (so just 0/1 resolution)

2) I get very large circles, going out of my scope

(I attach here two examples).
Can anybody help me to set the right parameters?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried `Layer Properties → Symbology → Heatmap`?

Comment: @ahmadhanb, thanks. I tried that it's a good solution, but I actually need to get a real raster, not just a display.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution myself ;-)

My mistake was in the resolution of the heatmap
The default value is 100 degrees, which correspond more or less to 1000Km, while I need a much higer resolution.
So if I use a radium of 0,001 degrees, I get the expected result.

[image]

I also found a good tutorial here
https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/creating_heatmaps.html

Hope this is useful for somebody else.

Massimo